# How to add query var to CSS URL when using HtmlHelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Currently we do this:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

...which results in this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css">
```

But what I want to get is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css?v=1.2.3">
```

(notice the query var at the end of the href)

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic.css?v=1.2.3');
```

...it still outputs this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css">
```

Is there a way to add query vars to resource URLs without manually writing the full `<link>...</link>` into the layout?

I read [the section in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css) and there is no mention of how to do this.

PS: Why I want to do this is irrelevant to answering the question, but if you're curious, I use this strategy to prevent issues caching problems that result when returning users view pages that need updated CSS. Incrementing the query var forces the new file to load rather than the outdated cached version.

Comment: it won't help solving your problem, but I like to perform the same by using a timestamp at the end of the URL (same for JS). That way I don't have to care if I modified the var or not so that if forces to redownload. But of course it means the file is never cached. Could also be a timestamp of the last modification date of the file.

Comment: Which CakePHP version do you use? At least with CakePHP 2.3.7 your snippet works fine.

Comment: also just tested in 2.3 and it works as you have tried.

Comment: @Bartdude I actually do the modified date too. It works great. I just didn't want to go on too much of a tangent.

Comment: @TimJoyce Where specifically did you put it? In the layout file? If so maybe something else is interfering...

Comment: yes... I have it in the head of default.ctp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your app in bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);
```

turn debug off.

You now have timestamped assets.

If you want it in debug mode too, `Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', 'force');`

Comment: Wow. That's really cool! Is the timestamp the current time? Or is it from when the file was modified?

Comment: You should know with 1700 points that answers need to be accepted ;)